# How this line is working in this C++ code snippet?

Tags: c++, enums

In **main** function there is a line

```
vector<bookStatusEnum> booksStatus(numbooks, available);
```

can you please explain how this line is executing? i see there is no booksStatus function in the code snippet. so what is it actually.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct book
{
    string title, author;

    inline bool operator<(const book& other) const
    {
        if (author != other.author)
            return author < other.author;

        return title < other.title;
    }
};

void ReadInBooks(vector<book> & allBooks)
{
    string temp;

    book currentBook;

    while (cin >> temp, temp != "END")
    {
        currentBook.title = "";

        bool first = true;

        while (*(temp.end() - 1) != '"')
        {
            if (!first)
                currentBook.title += ' ';

            first = false;
            currentBook.title += temp;

            cin >> temp;
        }

        if (!first)
            currentBook.title += ' ';

        currentBook.title += temp;

        // Ignore 'by'
        cin >> temp;
        // ignore the space after the by
        cin.ignore();

        getline(cin, currentBook.author);
        allBooks.push_back(currentBook);
    }
}

enum bookStatusEnum { available, borrowed, returned };

int main()
{
    vector<book> allBooks;
    ReadInBooks(allBooks);
    int numBooks = allBooks.size();
    std::sort(allBooks.begin(), allBooks.end());

    vector<bookStatusEnum> booksStatus(numBooks, available);

    map<string, int> positionInAllBooks;
    for (int i = 0; i < numBooks; ++i)
        positionInAllBooks[allBooks[i].title] = i;

    vector<bool> borrowed(allBooks.size(), false);
    vector<bool> returned(allBooks.size(), false);

    string command;
    string bookName;
    while (cin >> command, command != "END")
    {
        if (command == "BORROW")
        {
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, bookName);
            int pos = positionInAllBooks[bookName];
            borrowed[pos] = true;
            returned[pos] = false;
        }

        else if (command == "RETURN")
        {
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, bookName);
            returned[positionInAllBooks[bookName]] = true;
        }

        else // SHELVE
        {
            int previous = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < numBooks; ++i)
            {
                if (!borrowed[i])
                    previous = i;
                else if (returned[i])
                {
                    if (previous == -1)
                        cout << "Put " << allBooks[i].title << " first\n";
                    else
                        cout << "Put " << allBooks[i].title << " after " << allBooks[previous].title << '\n';

                    returned[i] = false;
                    borrowed[i] = false;
                    previous = i;
                }
            }

            cout << "END\n";
        }
    }
}
```

*P.S: I didn't find a suitable title for it. please feel free to suggest.*

Comment: Isn't that just constructor parameters for the vector?

Comment: it can be rewrited like `vector<bookStatusEnum> booksStatus{numbooks, available};`

Comment: that line is just saying create me a vector of enums with size 'numbooks' and initialized to 'available'. The name of the vector will be 'booksStatus'

Comment: You should remove all the irrelevant code (i.e. most of it) and leave a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bookStatus` is a `vector`, an array, and it contains elements of type `bookStatusEnum`.

As stated in the C++ documentation, that constructor should be:

**vector(size_type count, const T& value**, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());

- Constructs the container with *count* copies of elements with value *value*.

So, `numbooks` is defined as an integer and is the first parameter of the called constructor, therefore that is *count*, the size of the vector; and `available` is an enumerator part of `bookStatusEnum`, the *value*,  (technically in c++, the enum values by default are some integer type).

Therefore the vector contains `numbooks` copies of the value `available`.

```
vector<bookStatusEnum> booksStatus(numbooks, available);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short explanation:  it constructs a `std::vector<bookStatusEnum>` named `booksStatus` with `numbooks` elements, each initialised to `available`.    (Assuming `numbooks` is in the range of values that a `std:vector<bookStatusEnum>::size_type` can represent).  If it fails to do this, the program will abort.

Long explanation follows .....

Since

- there is a preceding `using namespace std`  (and no other `using` directives)
- there are preceding variables in scope - `numbooks` which is of type `int` and `available` which is of type `bookStatusEnum`

the effect of

```
vector<bookStatusEnum> booksStatus(numbooks, available);
```

is a definition of a variable named `booksStatus` which is of type `std::vector<bookStatusEnum>` which is initialised using a constructor that can accept two arguments, one of integral type and the other of type `bookStatusEnum`.

Reading the documentation for `std::vector`, we find it is a templated class with a constructor declared as something like;

```
vector(size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

where

- `size_type` (which is actually named `std::vector<bookStatusEnum>::size_type`) is an implementation defined `unsigned` integral type;
- `T` is the template parameter (i.e. the type `bookStatusEnum` if our vector is a `std::vector<bookStatusEnum>`) and;
- The third parameter is given a default value, so this constructor can
  accept two arguments.

To call this constructor, the variable `numbooks` is converted from `int` to `size_type` using modulo arithmetic (i.e. the converted value between `0` and the maximum value a `size_type` can represent), and `available` is passed by `const` reference.

The allocator (supplied by default) is an object that the vector will use to allocate memory.

The net effect of the statement is that `bookStatus` is of type `std::vector<bookStatusEnum>`.   The number of elements in that vector is `numbooks`  (as converted to `size_type` using modulo arithmetic) and each element has the value `available`.

If the construction fails (e.g. the allocator fails to allocate memory to hold the elements) an exception will be thrown.   Since there is no `try`/`catch` block, this will cause program termination (by calling `abort()`).

If construction succeeds, the object will exist until its containing scope ends.  In this case, that is when `main()` returns, so the vector's destructor is called as the program ends.   The effect of that destructor is releasing all memory used by the vector (i.e. the set of elements ceases to exist).

Simple!